# ORA-30036 UNDOTBS1

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> declare
  2  num float(10);
  3  begin
  4  num:=1;
  5  loop
  6  insert into integer values(num);
  7  num:= num+1;
  8  exit when num>99999;
  9  end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'
 ORA-06512: at line 6
```

what is this ORA-30036 error and how to solve it.I am running oracle plsql procedure . can some one find solution for it.

Comment: Add more space to the undo tablespace before retrying

Comment: additional solutions IMHO to what @Sami correctly suggested would be to add a commit to the loop that commits every e.g. 10.000 rows. Or if you just need the numbers from 1 to x for something, you don't even need a table, you can just use `select level from dual connect by level <= 100000`

Comment: Ok @Sami and peter thanks for the reply. The problem get solved by limiting the loop . I just edited at line no 8 to (exit when num>9999) and it worked .

Comment: But i still want a procedure to insert more than 10000 queries into table. If u can provide the code to that. Thanks peter and sami